# Functional interface method calling

Tags: java, functional-interface

Why does this code return no output?

```
public class Test {
public static Runnable print() {
    return () -> System.out.println("Hello world!!!");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {       
    Runnable r = Test ::print;
    r.run();
}
```

}
This looks correct `Runnable r = Test ::print`(but Intellij adds warning that print method won't be called).
thanks in advance for explanation!

Comment: `print` is returning a (second) Runnable, not running it (and `print` is being called, just its return value value ignored) - did you mean to do `Runnable r = Test.print();`?

Comment: One of many reasons to avoid returning a functional type from methods, but to call methods with lambdas or method references at the call site.

Comment: y, sorry for confusing. but why its ignored?

Comment: you would have to do something like  `r.run().run()` **but** that will **not compile** since `run()` is declared to return `void` (correct would be: `Supplier<Runnable> r = Test1::print; r.get().run();`)

Comment: @LouisWasserman agree, this is task from Oracle exam preparation))

Comment: @user85421 could you please explain why return value is ignored?

Comment: quoting myself: "`run()` is declared to return `void`"

Comment: maybe easier to think about it like: `Runnable r = Test::print` is like `Runnable r = () -> print;` and `() -> print` is **not** calling `print` but creating an instance of `class Runnable { public void run() { print(); } }` which is then assigned to `r` - similarly `return () -> System.out.println(...);` is not calling `println` but creating an instance of `class Runnable { public void run() { System.out.println(...); } }`. In `public void run() { print(); }` the value returned by `print` is *ignored*.  ((just for thinking, not exact))

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, IntelliJ is saying that "Result of 'Test.print()' is ignored", not that `print` won't be called.

What is the "Result of `print`"? Well, `print` returns a `Runnable` - this:

```
() -> System.out.println("Hello world!!!")
```

How did you ignore it? You assigned a method reference of `Test::print` to a `Runnable`:

```
Runnable r = Test::print;
```

`Runnable` represents a function that takes no arguments and returns `void` (i.e. no return value). You are saying that `print`, which is declared to return a `Runnable` should be assigned to `r`, *which stores a function that returns nothing*. That is clearly ignoring the return value of `print`.

Note that you are not assigning the return value of `print` to `r`, you are assigning the method `print` *itself* to `r`, not calling `print` at all until `r.run()`.

Assigning the return value of `print` to `r` would be written as:

```
Runnable r = Test.print();
```

This is not "ignoring the result of `print`", because you are assigning that result in `r`.

Let's look at a less confusing example would be:

```
public static String getString() {
    return "some string";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = Test::getString;
    r.run();
}
```

In the same way, you are saying that `getString`, which is declared to return a `String` should be assigned to `r`, *which stores a function that returns nothing*. The fact that `print` returns specifically a `Runnable` is not relevant to `r`. All that matters is, `print` returns *something*, and `r` does not return a value, so you are ignoring the return value of `print`.